# indexeddb implementation in angularjs2

Tags: typescript, angular, indexeddb

I am looking for an implementation of indexeddb with Angularjs2. I came across this api https://github.com/gilf/angular2-indexeddb; however I see less activity in this project currently and it does not look like production ready. Does any body has a better recommendation for indexeddb api implementation for Angularjs2. https://mozilla.github.io/localForage/ seems like a good option however not sure about its integration with Angularjs 2.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Check out [JsStore](http://jsstore.net/) . It provides typescript support. So you will be easily able to use it angular2, angular4 or any typescript technology.

Here is the article explaining how to implement indexeddb crud operation in angular4 - http://ujjwalguptaofficial.blogspot.in/2017/10/angular4-crud-operation-in-indexeddb.html